# GraphQL + JWT Auth + Axios isn't working and throwing a error: Error: Access denied! You need to be authorized to perform this action

Tags: node.js, axios, graphql, jwt

I Have a backend with GraphQL and I use JWT Auth to protect it.
When I sent my GraphQL request using Insomnia, it works properly!
However when I sent using Axios it doesn't work. I'm Using React Native

Some points to consider:

- Jwt isn't expired, because I can copy/paste it and use using Insomnia
- I can do the same request using other methods, for example: Insomnia, direct call using other scripts
- API_URI: http://localhost:3000/development/,
- Axios Version (app): 0.27.2
- graphql version (app): 15.5.1
- graphql-tag version (app): 2.12.5

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
import config from '../../config';
import store from '../stores';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.API_URI,
});

api.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  const { token, pushNotificationToken } = store.getState().user;
  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  config.headers.pushnotificationtoken = pushNotificationToken || '';

  return config;
});

api.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  console.log(
    '\n======================= STARTING REQUEST ===========================\n',
  );
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 2));
  console.log(
    '\n======================= ENDING REQUEST ===========================\n',
  );
  return request;
});

api.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  console.log(
    '\n======================= STARTING RESPONSE ===========================\n',
  );
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  console.log(
    '\n======================= ENDING RESPONSE ===========================\n',
  );

  return response;
});

export async function apiRequest<ResponseType>(
  body: any,
): Promise<ResponseType> {
  const response = await api.post('graphql', body);

  const { data } = response;

  if (data.errors && data.errors.length > 0) {
    throw new Error(data.errors[0].message || 'Ops! An error has occurred.');
  }

  return data.data;
}

export default api;
```

Response from backend Using Axios:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "errors": [{
            "message": "Access Denied",
            "locations": [{
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3
            }],
            "path": [
                "getAllOrders"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
                "exception": {
                    "stacktrace": [
                        "Error: Access denied! You need to be authorized to perform this action!",
                        "    at /home/agostinho/Documents/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT/v1/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT-back-end-2020/.webpack/service/src/webpack:/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/auth-middleware.js:13:1",
                        "    at dispatchHandler (/home/agostinho/Documents/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT/v1/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT-back-end-2020/.webpack/service/src/webpack:/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/resolvers/helpers.js:82:1)"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }],
        "data": null
    },
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
        "access-control-expose-headers": "WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "vary": "origin",
        "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
        "content-length": "601",
        "date": "Tue, 14 Jun 2022 15:32:37 GMT",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "keep-alive": "timeout=5"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {
            "FormData": null
        },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer + MY JWT TOKEN GOES HERE",
            "pushnotificationtoken": ""
        },
        "baseURL": "http://10.0.2.2:3000/development/",
        "method": "post",
        "url": "graphql",
        "data": "{\"query\":\"query getAllOrders {\\n  getAllOrders {\\n    id\\n    status\\n    table\\n    items {\\n      id\\n      description\\n      quantity\\n      priceCents\\n    }\\n    totalOrderPriceCents\\n    createdAt\\n  }\\n}\\n\"}"
    },
    "request": {
        "UNSENT": 0,
        "OPENED": 1,
        "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
        "LOADING": 3,
        "DONE": 4,
        "readyState": 4,
        "status": 200,
        "timeout": 0,
        "withCredentials": true,
        "upload": {},
        "_aborted": false,
        "_hasError": false,
        "_method": "POST",
        "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:3000/development/graphql",
        "_response": "{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Acesso não autorizado\",\"locations\":[{\"line\":2,\"column\":3}],\"path\":[\"getAllOrders\"],\"extensions\":{\"code\":\"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR\",\"exception\":{\"stacktrace\":[\"Error: Access denied! You need to be authorized to perform this action!\",\"    at /home/agostinho/Documents/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT/v1/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT-back-end-2020/.webpack/service/src/webpack:/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/auth-middleware.js:13:1\",\"    at dispatchHandler (/home/agostinho/Documents/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT/v1/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT-back-end-2020/.webpack/service/src/webpack:/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/resolvers/helpers.js:82:1)\"]}}}],\"data\":null}\n",
        "_url": "http://10.0.2.2:3000/development/graphql",
        "_timedOut": false,
        "_trackingName": "unknown",
        "_incrementalEvents": false,
        "responseHeaders": {
            "access-control-expose-headers": "WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "vary": "origin",
            "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
            "content-length": "601",
            "Date": "Tue, 14 Jun 2022 15:32:37 GMT",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5"
        },
        "_requestId": null,
        "_headers": {
            "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "Bearer + jwt goes here",
            "pushnotificationtoken": ""
        },
        "_responseType": "",
        "_sent": true,
        "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {
            "access-control-expose-headers": "WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "vary": "origin",
            "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
            "content-length": "601",
            "date": "Tue, 14 Jun 2022 15:32:37 GMT",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "keep-alive": "timeout=5"
        },
        "_subscriptions": [],
        "responseURL": "http://10.0.2.2:3000/development/graphql"
    }
}
```

The same request using Insomnia:

[image: insomnia]

Insomnia Timeline:

[image: insomnia timeline]

Insomnia Header
[image]

console.log(response.request):

```json
{
  "UNSENT": 0,
  "OPENED": 1,
  "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
  "LOADING": 3,
  "DONE": 4,
  "readyState": 4,
  "status": 200,
  "timeout": 0,
  "withCredentials": true,
  "upload": {},
  "_aborted": false,
  "_hasError": false,
  "_method": "POST",
  "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:3000/development/graphql",
  "_response": "{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Acesso não autorizado\",\"locations\":[{\"line\":2,\"column\":3}],\"path\":[\"getAllOrders\"],\"extensions\":{\"code\":\"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR\",\"exception\":{\"stacktrace\":[\"Error: Access denied! You need to be authorized to perform this action!\",\"    at /home/agostinho/Documents/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT/v1/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT-back-end-2020/.webpack/service/src/webpack:/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/auth-middleware.js:13:1\",\"    at dispatchHandler (/home/agostinho/Documents/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT/v1/MY-MOBILE-PROJECT-back-end-2020/.webpack/service/src/webpack:/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/resolvers/helpers.js:82:1)\"]}}}],\"data\":null}\n",
  "_url": "http://10.0.2.2:3000/development/graphql",
  "_timedOut": false,
  "_trackingName": "unknown",
  "_incrementalEvents": false,
  "responseHeaders": {
    "access-control-expose-headers": "WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "vary": "origin",
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
    "content-length": "601",
    "Date": "Tue, 14 Jun 2022 17:42:39 GMT",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5"
  },
  "_requestId": null,
  "_headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Bearer eyJ........",
    "pushnotificationtoken": ""
  },
  "_responseType": "",
  "_sent": true,
  "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {
    "access-control-expose-headers": "WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "vary": "origin",
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
    "content-length": "601",
    "date": "Tue, 14 Jun 2022 17:42:39 GMT",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "keep-alive": "timeout=5"
  },
  "_subscriptions": [],
  "responseURL": "http://10.0.2.2:3000/development/graphql"
}
```

Comment: can you add screenshot of "timeline" & "header" of insomnia ?.
also ```console.log(response.request) ```

Comment: @bogdanoff Of course. I edited there!

Comment: hmm.. thats odd, both have almost same headers but different result. I think token or auth header is malformed. Make sure it doesn't have  tab instead of space and compare token manually before sending. Also try without "pushnotificationtoken" header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was a behavior at my authorizer context!

The Insomnia was sending `Authorization` with the `A` as Uppercase, however, axios was sending `authorization` with the `a` as lowercase.

I needed to debug my backend, so I use the following to handle with that:

`const Authorization = ctx.event.headers.Authorization || ctx.event.headers.authorization`

Thus, my authorizer context will handle with two situations.

The final code:

```
export default function context (ctx: any): any {
  const Authorization = ctx.event.headers.Authorization || ctx.event.headers.authorization
  if (typeof Authorization !== 'undefined' && Authorization.indexOf('Bearer') > -1) {
     try {
        const AuthorizationToken = Authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
        const customer = jwt.verify(AuthorizationToken, process.env.JWT_CUSTOMER_SECRET) as CustomerContext

        customer.devicePushNotificationToken = ctx.event.headers.pushnotificationtoken

        return { customer }
     } catch (err) { }
  } else {
    return null
  }
}
```